# AngularJS - Accessing to an input array with ng-model dynamic name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have 3 rows with 13 input fields in each row.
All the follow the rule of have a ng-model like:

First row: `field[1][{1-13}]`
Second row: `field[2][{1-13}]`
Third row: `field[3][{1-13}]`

So if I want to access to the first row and to the field #6 I do it like `$scope.field[1][6]`. The problem is that I cannot access like this to the field.

This is the HTML of the input:

```
<input ng-model='field[1][6]' type='text' />
```

I've tried to access by using: `$scope.field[1][6]` but it says that "field" is undefined.

Here is how I am trying to access it from my AngularJS controller:

```
angular.module("myModule")
    .controller("myModuleController", ["$scope","$http", function($scope,$http) {
        console.log($scope.field[1][2]);
}]);
```

- This fields are created when the DOM loads and they cannot be generated with ng-repeat because some deeper factors.

I am new at AngularJS, thanks for the patience.

Comment: Did you included your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found what the issue is in case someone needs to know.
Basically, in order for the array of inputs to be inside the `$scope` it needs to be looped with `ng-repeat`. So, even though you give the `ng-model` directive to the input it won't know about it because it wasn't processed by AngularJS.

**Conclusion:** You cannot just read the array of inputs this way. I worked it around by giving a dynamic ID, like `field-1-6` and then using:

```
angular.element("#myApp").find("#field-" + firstIndex + "-" + secondIndex );
```

In my point of view is much better to just redo your code and make it be generated by angular. In my case it can't be done because the client doesn't want that piece of code upgraded. So, its a good workaround if you are in my situation.

;)

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem accessing that way. Maybe you have some error elsewhere.

```js
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('Test', Test);

function Test($scope) {
  $scope.fields = [
    [
      {name: '1-1'},
      {name: '1-2'},
      {name: '1-3'}
    ],
    [
      {name: '2-1'},
      {name: '2-2'}
    ],
    [
      {name: '3-1'}
    ]
  ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <div ng-repeat='(i, lv1) in fields'>
    <div ng-repeat='(j, lv2) in lv1'>
      <input type='text' ng-model='lv2.name'>
      <input type='text' ng-model='fields[i][j].name'>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <input type='text' ng-model='fields[1][1].name'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works when you put it like that but still I cannot access to the field value through the controller. I should also be able to access to the array of inputs as "$scope.fields" but no, still undefined.

Comment: @mkmnstr can you show your code on how you are trying to access them?

Comment: @lcycool I just updated my question with the code I am using. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The code you have updated your question with unfortunately does not show

1. how you are initializing $scope.field
2. how you are using it in ng-repeat

`<input ng-model='field[1][6]' type='text' />` can mean different things depending on the first two points.

Without context angular will read it like this http://jsfiddle.net/3tsw98yf/

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Not really. Well, the thing is there is no initialization. They piece of code cannot be modified and well, I had to use it by ID only, and setting a custom ID name. But thanks!!

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the clarification.